# Op Amp Selection, Linear DC Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I need help selecting an Op-Amp for a project I am working on. It's been a long time since I worked with Op Amps in school. So long ago, 741 was a high-performance op-amp. The project is a Constant Current Constant Voltage 14-volt 5-amp charger/bench power supply. The circuit below is the voltage regulator half of the circuit.

It is slightly different from most designs as it controls the negative rail. The reason for going this route is thermal management. It allows you to attach transistors to the heat sinks without isolation pads. The circuit is easily modified to drive parallel NPN transistors for a high current DC supply. The other benefit is that it is a semi-quasi low-drive voltage regulator to lessen the pass elements' heat burden.

A couple of comments: U1, R2, C1, and C2 provide the 5-volt reference and "soft start". D1 is an OR diode and the point where the Constant Current regulator interfaces to take control of M1. I show an ADA 4099, but do not know if it is a good fit.

What am I looking for spec-wise? I know PSRR and CMRR specifications are essential. I don't know what to look for. Can anyone take a little time and help me, please?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I'd say you will be fine with any unity-stable modern (MOSFET/JFET input) opamp. CMRR and PSRR are usually so high on these nowadays that it's not much of a consideration unless you're doing some kind of low-noise or precision amp. I think that the slew rate, rail to rail ability, package/footprint, and bias current consumption will be more important figures for you.

Comment: Rail to Rail in and out a.k.a. **RRIO** is a feature I would look for.  The 741 didn't have that.

Comment: Dereck, If you need to reach 0 V output you will need a negative rail voltage. It doesn't have to have a lot of current compliance (not with a FET.) But it is needed. You also should be using ground-return current monitoring, I think. So the circuit is a little more complicated. (As I imagine it, anyway.)

Comment: *So long ago, 741 was a high-performance op-amp* <-- you must be older than me LOL

Comment: Delta12 how would I identify a Unity Stable device?
Aaron I believe the device shown is rail to rail although I don't know if it is a requirement for this application.
Periblepsis although not shown, the output will be variable from 10 to 15 volts.